# Prove that if A is a linear transformation on a finite dimensional vector space V, then $V \cong Range(A)\oplus Nullspace(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra

a)Prove that if A is a linear transformation on a finite dimensional vector space V, then $V\cong Range(A)\oplus Nullspace(A)$.

b)Give an example that shows $Range(A)\cap Nullspace(A)\neq\{0\}$. In particular, $V\neq Range(A)\oplus Nullspace(A)$. Why doesn't this contradict (a)?

I am thinking of setting a basis for V then 
Showing this basis is made up of elements from the null space and range? Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is that $=$ and $\simeq$ are different relations. For example, $\{1,2\} \simeq \{2,3\}$ as sets, because there is a bijection $f \colon \{1,2\} \to \{2,3\}$ that is compatible with the set structure. But $\{1,2\} \neq \{2,3\}$, because $1$ is in the first but not in the second set.

To elaborate further, one needs to know how you define the $\oplus$ operation. While in most concrete examples it is an operation between two subspaces of the same linear space, the actual definition uses a universality property.

P.S. Unless you provide more details about your own thinking on this question, I'm afraid you'll see more down-votes on what is actually an interesting question.

Comment: I am thinking of setting a basis for V then Showing this basis is made up of elements from the null space and range? Would that work?